# How to Use WP_REDIRECT and Continue Parent Execution

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

In WordPress, how do you use the WP_REDIRECT() function from a custom plugin, and then pass back execution to the parent function?

When I use WP_REDIRECT, I am noticing that the execution is not passed back to the parent function.

**Sharing Code - UPDATE:**

How can I hook into the below plugins' **do_action( 'otherplugin_new_user_moderation', $customer_id );** hook and use the below redirect function to force the home page to load (from my plugin); and then pass the execution flow back to the parent (other plugin) so that the wc_add_notice is added to the home page (instead of the current page).

```
function redirect() {
    wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
    exit();
}
```

Another Plugin - handles moderation:

```
do_action( 'otherplugin_created_customer', $customer_id, $new_customer_data );

if ( 'yes' === \get_option( 'otherplugin_moderate_registrations', 'yes' ) ) {
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'otherplugin_moderation_required', true);

    do_action( 'otherplugin_new_user_moderation', $customer_id );

    wc_add_notice( __( 'Your registration has been submitted successfully.', 'other-plugin' ) );
} else {
    do_action( 'otherplugin_new_user_auto_approved', $customer_id, $password );

    wc_add_notice( __( 'Your registration was processed successfully and a password has been sent to your email address.', 'other-plugin' ) );
}
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything from my end.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to share your code snippet or function where you are trying to use this?

Also to quite the reference docs for wordpress, it's reccomended to to use wp_safe_redirect();

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Comment: Hi! I have updated my post, please see "Sharing Code - UPDATE". I will definitely look into and use wp_safe_redirect(). Thank you!